# Remove last line segment of an OpenLayers.Control.Measure

Tags: openlayers-2

i'm using OpenLayers library, i'm trying to delete the last line segment of a drawing realized with the following code:

```
layerLine = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("layerLine");
layerLine.id = "id_layer_line";
map.addLayer(layerLine);

lineControl = new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
        id: 'id_layer_line',
        persist: true,
        layer: layerLine ,
        //immediate:true,
        handlerOptions: {
            layerOptions: {styleMap: styleMap},
        }
    }
);
```

But the layerLine has no features (empty array), it means i can't access to line segments, is there are any way to do this?

Comment: You don't normally assign a layer to a Measure control.When drawing, the drawing actually takes place on a temporary layer controlled by the Path handler. If you can set a break-point while measuring, look at the map layer collection - you should see a layer with the name of the handler.